# docker compose config for multiple instances of one image with different arguments

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a cli application that can run two services based on the input argument.

```
1- app serve // to run a web server
2- app work  // to run a long-running background worker
```

they share the same code. what do I need when for deployment?

```
 A: two separate containers or
 B: two processes in the same container
```

**And what would be the docker-compose config ?**

Comment: This highly depends on your application and what you want to do. It on how closely the two processes are coupled (or how closely you want to couple them). If they are in two containers you can enable communication via network sockets or shared volumes. I really depends on what you want to do. Generally, people recommend [one process per container](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have one process per container, I would suggest to have a generic image (and Dockerfile) which can run as worker or as server.

The Dockerfile file should set the entrypoint to the app, e.g. `ENTRYPOINT ["/path_to_my_app/myapp"]` but not the `CMD`. When the user invokes the command from the command line, he can start the worker with `docker run IMAGENAME work` or the server with `docker run IMAGENAME serve`.

To define both services in a compose file, you need to override the `command` field for each service.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
      build: ./docker    # common Dockerfile
      image: IMAGENAME
      ports:
          - "8090:8090"
      command: ["serve"]

  worker:
      build: ./docker    # common Dockerfile
      image: IMAGENAME   # reuse image
      ports:
          - "8091:8091"
      command: ["work"]
```

The benefit of this solution over a solution with two separate images, is a gain in maintainability. Since there is only one Dockerfile and one image, both services should be always compatible.

Comment: great!. but are you sure if command option you set in docker-compose will always append to ENTRYPOINT you defined in Dockerfile?

Comment: In my experience, it only appends if the `ENTRYPOINT` is defined with the `[arg1, arg2, ...]` notation (opposed to plain strings). To be sure, use the bracket notation for `command` and `ENTRYPOINT`. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

"Note: If CMD is used to provide default arguments for the ENTRYPOINT instruction, both the CMD and ENTRYPOINT instructions should be specified with the JSON array format."

Answer (score 1):

after some googling, I found that as @sauerburger said in comments, better to have one process per container.

But to have multiple containers each for running my main app with a specific argument (ie. one for main app and one for worker) I need to have multiple Dockerfiles. the in my docker-compose i can referenc them separately.

but how to have different dockerfiles for a project?

the prefered solution is to have a docker directory in which each part has its own folder. for my application it will be like this:

```
- docker
    - web
        -Dockerfile
    - worker
        -Dockerfile
```

then in each Dockerfile I have a common entrypoint and a distinct cmd:

```
-in web Dockerfile :
    - ENTRYPOINT ["/path_to_my_app/myapp"]
    - CMD ["web"]

-in worker Dockerfile :
    - ENTRYPOINT ["/path_to_my_app/myapp"]
    - CMD ["worker"]
```

after doing this my docker-compose file will reference them like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
      web:
          # will build ./docker/web/Dockerfile
          build: ./docker/web
          ports:
              - "8090:8090"

      worker:
          # will build ./docker/worker/Dockerfile
          build: ./docker/worker
          ports:
              - "8091:8091"
```

Comment: Wouldn’t we end up with 2 almost identical Dockerfile copies? Which should be manually kept in sync every time, when there is a need to make changes?